# How to get FileName from TextBoxFor type=file ASP.NET MVC 4?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have file upload control in my View:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.File, "", new { type = "file" })
```

Model:

```
public class ImageModel
{
    public HttpPostedFile File {get; set;}
}
```

I want to get the extension of uploaded file. I tried this, where image is the file from form:

```
string extension = Path.GetExtension(image.File.Name);
```

but it returns null. Are there any other possibilities to get file extension?

Comment: Are you sure if your file is not null?

Comment: First check whether you get the uploaded file to you `HttpPostedFile File` property. Seems to be the problem is there. Your code seems to be correct.

Comment: Yes, I have the file in the property, I can save it on disk but the only problem is with reading file name.

Comment: @guitargirl image.File.Name is null or Path.GetExtension(image.File.Name)? What is the value of image.File.Name?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the html file upload control

```
<input type="file" id="fileToUpload" name="file" />
```

Then in the controller add function as follows

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult FileUpload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    string extension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For client side validation of file extension you can use JavaScript. Call it when you file input is changed

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var onChanged = function() {
        var inputFile = document.getElementById("uploadBtn");    
        var fileName = inputFile.value.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');



        if (validateFileExtension(fileName) {
            //extension is valid
        }else {
            //show error 

        }
    }

    function validateFileExtension(name) {
        if (!/(\.xlsx)$/i.test(name)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```